# Return a SQL result set as a blob via ODBC

Tags: c++, sql, odbc, sql-server-2012

using ODBC as the transport layer is convenient in that you easily connect via tcp to a remote machine. The drawback is all the round trips over the connection. 
At the launch of the thick client, many data sets are required some with thousands of lines. This is data needed before thing #1 can be done by the user.

What I would like to do is create a single object (blob perhaps) to return with a single round trip meaning condense the result set into a table/blob/object that I can parse out upon receipt.

I can think of a few ugly ways to do this, something elegant would be great.

Comment: I think it all depends how you code your c++ program. If you use something like CRecordSet then yes, there will be thousands of round trips. However, if you know what you are after (e.g. Select col1 from table1) then you can use a minimum set of ODBC Api's for this and the library will not be doing any unnecessary calls

Comment: Using ODBC in any language, A call to Execute() is followed by multiple calls to Fetch (in a loop), one call for each row. The question is about packaging data to avoid this.

Comment: You can increase the rowset size, so that SQLFetch() retrieves many rows at a time. What is your code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean SQL Server. if you use forwardonly cursors, each SQLFetch will not require a round trip to the server. If you find its taking a long time to do that, it may be worth reviewing just how you are calling the ODBC API. Normally a fetch from a forward only cursor will be limited by your network throughput speed, and the only round trips needed will be TCP ack's.

Comment: Well I can use SQLFetchScroll() to retrieve many rows, but I was wondering about packaging with perhaps some compression using some server side cleverness.